# How to do multiple column unique-constraint in ormlite ( SQLite )

Tags: sql, sqlite, unique-constraint, ormlite

I'm using ormlite for Android and I'm trying to get a multiple column unique-constraint. As of now i'm only able to get a unique constraint on indiviudal columns like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `store_group_item` (`store_group_id` INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE ,
    `store_item_id` INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE ,
    `_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT );
```

and what I want is

```
CREATE TABLE `store_group_item` (`store_group_id` INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    `store_item_id` INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    `_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    UNIQUE( `store_group_id`, `store_item_id` );
```

In my model I've been using the following annotations for the unique columns:

```
@DatabaseField( unique = true )
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about using

```
@DatabaseField (uniqueCombo = true) 
String myField;
```

annotation instead - is it a matter of the uniqueIndexName being faster when accessing items in the table?

Comment: This is the right answer if you have version >= 4.20 which was added 4/30/2011. http://ormlite.com/changelog.txt. Good find!

Comment: Oh thanks :) but like I said - maybe Gray could clarify if there is a performance catch to this.

Answer (score 7):

**Edit:**

As @Ready4Android pointed out, we've since added in version 4.20 support for `uniqueCombo` annotation field.  Here are the docs:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/unique-combo

There should be no performance differences between using this mechanism versus the `uniqueIndexName` mentioned below.

---

Yes.  You can't do this with the `unique=true` tag but you can with a unique index.

```
@DatabaseField(uniqueIndexName = "unique_store_group_and_item_ids")
int store_group_id;
@DatabaseField(uniqueIndexName = "unique_store_group_and_item_ids")
int store_item_id;
```

This will create an index to accomplish the unique-ness but I suspect that the unique=true has a hidden index anyway.  See the docs:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/unique-index

I will look into allowing multiple unique fields.  May not be supported by all database types.

Comment: are these annotations possible with foreign Objects?